# why Elasticsearch doesn't return right results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using **Elasticsearch 6.2** configured with one cluster of **2 nodes**.

`GET _cluster/health`:

```
 {
    "cluster_name": "cluster_name",
    "status": "green",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 2,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
    "active_primary_shards": 47,
    "active_shards": 94,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 0,
    "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
    "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
    "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
    "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
    "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100
    }
```

`GET myindex/_settings`:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "url_split_analyzer": {
              "filter": "lowercase",
              "tokenizer": "url_split"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "url_split": {
              "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
              "type": "pattern"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
          "created": "6020499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here a snapshot of the `_mappings` structure:

```
    "myindex": {
        "mappings": {
          "mytype": {
            "properties": {
              "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              ............
              "active": {
                 "type": "short"
               },
             "id_domain": {
                "type": "short",
                "ignore_malformed": true
              },
            "url": {
                 "type": "text",
                 "similarity": "boolean",
                  "analyzer": "url_split_analyzer"
            }
           }
          .......
```

I have casually found documents, within my index, that I cannot find if I query the index using the `id_domain` property.

For example:

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search
{ 
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": { "active": 1 }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

output example:

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "mytype",
    "_id": "myurl",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id_domain": "73993",
        "active": 1,
        "url": "myurl",
        "@timestamp": "2018-05-21T10:55:16.247Z"
    }
}
....
```

returns a list of documents where I found `id_domain` that I cannot find querying against that id domain, like this:

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
        "id_domain": 73993 // with or without " got the same result
      }
  }
}
```

output

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I cannot understand why this happens.
I also tried to **reindex** the index but I got the same result.

I am convinced that I'm missing something. 
Is there any reason about that behaviour?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping, `id_domain` has type `short`, but in your document you have a value that is out of the bounds for short values ([-32,768 to 32,767]), i.e. 73993.

You need to change the type to `integer` and all will be fine

Comment: I'm astonished!!!! I did not notice that! surely that creates problems! Is it possible to change data types runtime or I need to reindex everything?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to reindex your data.